# How can i manage leveldb database to cope with Django framework

Tags: django, database, nosql, leveldb

i am trying to develop a web application that uses leveldb as a database, knowing that leveldb doesn't support an SGBD,how can i deal with it in order to manage data on django framework

I suggest to use a relational data base to manage users,sessions and other standard data, and try to use leveldb just for that purpose that i am using for.